OkHttp MockWebServer dispatch not getting triggered
Here's my code in isolation
fun getMockServerUrl(): String {
    val server = MockWebServer()
    server.dispatcher = object : Dispatcher() {
        override fun dispatch(request: RecordedRequest): MockResponse {
            println("dispatch hit ")
            TODO()
        }
    }
    server.start()
    val url = server.url(path = "")

    val api = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(url)
        ...
        .create(MyApi::class.java)

    Thread {
        api.getData().enqueue(
            object : Callback<String> {
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<String>, response: Response<String>) {
                    println("Response is ${response.body()}")
                }
            },
        )
    }.start()
    

    return url.toString().also {
        println("URL is $it")
    }
}

What's happening?

URL is $it gets invoked with proper localhost base URL and able to access the localhost from external browser. This means server is up and running
Response is null is getting printed, which is kinda expected
But dispatch hit is never printed. (Though it gets printed when accessed from an external browser) : That


The device had the proxy turned on (Charles). Turning that off fixed the issue.
